# i can't login to my database mssql node js + docker

Tags: node.js, sql-server

My problem is that i can't login to my database
and my password is right

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRn5L.png)

this is my config

```
const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'Super_Duper_Password',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'testdb',
    debug: true,
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true
    }
}
```

and this is for connecting to the database

```
let pool

const run = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('connection Opening...')
        pool = await sql.connect(config)
        const { recordset } = await sql.query`selct * from users;`;
        
        console.log(recordset)
    }   catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }   finally {
        await pool.close()
        console.log('Connection closed')
    }
}

run()
```

Comment: can you login via SQL Server management Studio?

Comment: Did you expose MSSQL port when running your container?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some more information. Is MSSQL running on the host, or in a Docker container? What port(s) does the MSSQL container publish via the -p or --publish switch on the docker run command line? Is the Node app on the host, or in a Docker container? Probably most important of all: what's the full and complete error message that you get? (As text.)